# Get Javascript variables to a PHP file using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, ajax-request

I am a newbie in web base applications development and Im learning AJAX. Here is my problem, I'm trying to make an AJAX request with some variables (user inputs) and get the php file with the same variables. Below is my code, if there something I am missing or I am doing wrong please let me know, I will appreciated any help! Thank you.

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;
try{
  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }catch (e){
   try{
     ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     }catch (e) {
  try{
     ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }catch (e){
    document.getElementById("Alert").innerHTML= "*Your browser broke!";
    document.getElementById("Alert").style.color = '#E00000 ';
     return false;
   }
  }
 }
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('display');
      ajaxDisplay.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
     }
   }
 var input_building = document.getElementById('building').value;
 var input_room = document.getElementById('room').value;
 var queryString = "?building=" + input_building + "&room=" + input_room;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "map.php" + queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(); 
}
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
  <select id="building" name="building">
     <option value="#" default >Select</option>
     <option value="Luis C. Monzon">Luis C. Monzon</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="room" name="room" placeholder="eg. 208B / CH 116" >
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="submit" onclick="ajaxFunction()" >
  <p id="display"></p>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php>
  $building = $_GET['building'];
  $room = $_GET['room'];

  echo "<h1>".$room." ".$building."</h1>";
  ?>
```

Comment: What is the result you're getting? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Have you heard of jQuery?

Comment: Change `ajaxDisplay.value` to `ajaxDisplay.innerHTML`

Comment: Disregard my answer rofl. :P

Comment: @mplungjan Could you please add that as an answer?

Comment: @mimipc Note that AJAX is possible without jquery! ;) Especially for beginners it is helpful to work without a library

Comment: @mimipc Because you've heard of jQuery, you have to use it? Would using jQuery solve the problem? No!

Comment: Ok, sorry, jQuery wouldn't solve the problem. I just find it easier for beginners to learn AJAX concepts (even if it's a good thing to know the underlying code). I wanted to suggest jQuery as he said he was a newbie, but I totally agree with your posts.

Comment: @Asad - seems someone else got to post my comment as answer while I slept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a `value` property on a `<p>` element. You should be setting its `innerHTML`. Value is used for input fields.

```
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

As requested, I will post my comment

In your code you need to change `ajaxDisplay.value` to `ajaxDisplay.innerHTML` - as elaborated by Juan, form fields have values and container tags have innerHTML.

To defend the use of jQuery a little - I basically agree that for simple JavaScript, loading an external library can be overkill - in the case of Ajax, I trust jQuery to cover all browsers needs.

Your code with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Get building</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { // run onload
  $("ajaxbutton").on("click",function() {
    var input_building = $('building').val();
    var input_room = $('room').val();
    var queryString = "?building=" + input_building + "&room=" + input_room;
    $("#display").load("map.php" + queryString); // get the room 
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="building" name="building">
  <option value="#" default >Select</option>
  <option value="Luis C. Monzon">Luis C. Monzon</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="room" name="room" placeholder="eg. 208B / CH 116" />
<input id="ajaxbutton" type="button" value="Find Building" />
<p id="display"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: for more control over the result you can change the load to

```
    $.get("map.php" + queryString,function(data) {
      // do something with data here - for example if you use JSON
      $("#display").html(data);
    });
```